# How to fix snmp v3 error "Request has reached maximum retries."?

Tags: c#, snmp

When I try to make SNMP V3 request it shows this error "Request has reached maximum retries." when it reach to target.Discovery(param), I have looked over the internet for a solution but I have ended with nothing, I don't know what causing it, and why it is happening, anything would help thank you very much

I have looked over stack overflow and I have found this question but with no answer [SNMP V3 discovery fails using SnmpSharpNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238825/snmp-v3-discovery-fails-using-snmpsharpnet)

```
IpAddress ipa = new IpAddress("localhost");
        UdpTarget target = new UdpTarget((IPAddress)ipa);
        SecureAgentParameters param = new SecureAgentParameters();

        if (!target.Discovery(param))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Discovery failed. Unable to continue...");
            target.Close();
            return;
        }
        // Construct a Protocol Data Unit (PDU)
        Pdu pdu = new Pdu();
        // Set the request type (default is Get)
        pdu.Type = PduType.Get;
        // Add variables you wish to query
        pdu.VbList.Add("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
        Oid oidVal1 = new Oid(new int[] { 1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0 });
        pdu.VbList.Add(oidVal1);
        Oid oidVal2 = new Oid("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0");
        pdu.VbList.Add(oidVal2);
        // optional: make sure no authentication or privacy is configured in the 
        // SecureAgentParameters class (see discovery section above)
        param.authPriv(
              "priv1",
               AuthenticationDigests.MD5, "test1234",
               PrivacyProtocols.AES128, "1234test");
        // Make a request. Request can throw a number of errors so wrap it in try/catch
        SnmpV3Packet result;
        try
        {
            result = (SnmpV3Packet)target.Request(pdu, param);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
            result = null;
        }
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.ScopedPdu.Type == PduType.Report)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SNMPv3 report:");
                foreach (Vb v in result.ScopedPdu.VbList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> ({1}) {2}",
                      v.Oid.ToString(),
                      SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(v.Value.Type), v.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (result.ScopedPdu.ErrorStatus == 0)
                {
                    foreach (Vb v in result.ScopedPdu.VbList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} -> ({1}) {2}",
                          v.Oid.ToString(),
                          SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(v.Value.Type), v.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SNMPError: {0} ({1}): {2}",
                      SnmpError.ErrorMessage(result.ScopedPdu.ErrorStatus),
                      result.ScopedPdu.ErrorStatus, result.ScopedPdu.ErrorIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        target.Close();
```